# How does one restore dump of block device in Linux

Tags: restore, dump

Lets say I create a dump of a block device like so

dump -0 -A L0.archive -f L0.dump /dev/sde1

Now in this case sde1 is not mounted, as to not be live.  So how can I restore sde1 from the other partition while sde1 is unmounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard process for restoring from a dump file is to recreate the filesystem (mkfs), then restore into the freshly-created filesystem.

If liveness of the filesystem is a concern (but it's not a critical fs like root, /usr, or /var) then you can mount the new fs away from where something would go looking for it, and remount it at its proper spot once the restore is complete.

Comment: I am asking how does one restore to the newly created file system.

Comment: To restore the whole level-0 dump, cd into the new filesystem and run 'restore -r -f L0.dump'